Error with Turbo Module after adding Swift file
I'm getting an error with adding my TurboModule if I add a swift file to the module - I have a bridging header and everything and still doesn't work. If i remove the swift file then it works again
` (ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCodegen/BleManagerSpec/BleManagerSpec.h:15:2)
13 |
14 | #ifndef __cplusplus

15 | #error This file must be compiled as Obj-C++. If you are importing it, you must change your file extension to .mm.
|  ^ This file must be compiled as Obj-C++. If you are importing it, you must change your file extension to .mm.
16 | #endif
17 |
18 | // Avoid multiple includes of BleManagerSpec symbols`

Steps to reproduce
npx create-react-native-library@latest BleYolanda
yarn install && npx pod-install && npx expo run:ios (expo doesn't use prebuild. I manage the android and ios directories). Note everything works here
in modules/demo-turbo-module/ios add ble-yolanda-Bridging-Header.h and BleYolanda.swift and run all of the commands again and I get the following errors
